# How can I make TextBox controls read-only when they are inside a disabled GroupBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, textbox

I have a `GroupBox` control in my Windows Forms application, inside of which I have placed some `TextBox` controls. How can I disable the `GroupBox` control while making the individual `TextBox` controls read-only?

Whenever I disable the `GroupBox`, all of the `TextBox` controls inside of it get disabled as well. I can't figure out how to make them read-only.

Comment: can you be little more verbose.. what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you disable a container control (such as a `GroupBox`), all of its children become disabled as well. That's just how it works in Windows; it's not possible to change that behavior.

Instead, you need to set the [`ReadOnly` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) of each individual `TextBox` control to true. If you disable the entire `GroupBox`, each `TextBox` control it contains will be disabled as well, which overrides the state of the `ReadOnly` property and prevents the user from copying its contents.

Once you've fixed the section of your code that disables the `GroupBox`, you can use a simple `foreach` loop to do the dirty work of setting the property on each `TextBox` control:

```
foreach (TextBox txt in myGroupBox.Controls)
{
    txt.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will make all the textboxes in the groupbox readonly.

```
foreach(TextBox t in groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                t.ReadOnly = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you set the *Enabled* property of a groupbox to false. All contents in it (textbox, etc.) will become disabled too. But you can still do it using:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)ctrl).ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not true. All of the contents will become *disabled*, which is not the same thing as read-only for a `TextBox`. A user can still select and copy text displayed in a read-only textbox. That's not possible if it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean here is that you want to disable the groupbox and at the same time - don't want the textboxes to be shown as grayed... If this is something you want to achieve, you better put these textboxes in Panel and then set them ReadOnly as you would do for any control.

Comment: Still won't work. If the panel is a child control of a disabled `GroupBox`, it will be disabled too. It's not clear why you'd want to introduce an additional `Panel` control in the first place.